# Replace history and then redirect in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser-history, redirect

While trying to access window.location or window.history directly, how can I do the following in AngularJS:

1. Replace the history for current location
2. Redirect to a new location

For example:

- user goes to "/#/loc1"
- I want the history to show they went to "/#/loc2"
- Then redirect to "/#/loc3"
- If they use the browser.back, it should return them to "#/loc2"

Answer (score 11):

Is this what you want?

```
$location.path('/blahblah').replace();
```

See [API Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location) for $location